Adding light from SW1 in a 3-way
I'm trying to add a light from Switch 1 because it's the closest to where the new light needs to be. Switch 2 and light are upstairs.
The wiring is 50 years old and I don't understand why the neutral wires are the only ones being connected to the switches, while the black HOT wire pretty much travels coupled all the way up to the light.
Can anyone explain why this is wired this way and how I can add a new light to the 3-way?


Neutral must be white.  White does not always mean neutral.  Neutrals should not be switched/on a switch, that is a no-no, but whites marked as hot can be on a switch.  This is for a nice simple single switch,  add in three ways and it starts to get confusing.  From the image, mistakes were made, and I would not add anything to that circuit, till the wires are sorted out.

Assuming the black wire is spliced through both switch boxes, and it is unswitched, and it is connected to a circuit breaker, then the explanation is that both switches were installed wrong.
It would also mean the lamp is never de-energized and shouldn't be touched unless the circuit breaker is off.
Some of this can be confirmed visually, but it's still a good idea to check the voltage from black to green to confirm.
Proximity to "SW1" is not going to be helpful unless you plan to make a lot of changes or run another cable upstairs.
